# Adblock Plus losing subscriptions and filters since last update

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, adblock

Adblock Plus recently updated itself (it opened the "Adblock Plus has been installed" tab), and since then it has not been saving filter lists (subscriptions) nor manually entered filters ("add your own filters") between Chrome session.

All previous config has apparently been wiped, and anything added only lasts until Chrome is closed/re-opened - at which point the config is blank again.

There have been no changes (by me) to Chrome or any extensions, but of course no way to tell if Google have done anything, or if any other extensions have updated without knowledge/approval.

Is there any way to check versions / downgrade to a working version? Or to debug the extension data, maybe making it read-only after appropriate config to see if that stops it being blanked?

Version info:-
Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m
Adblock Plus 1.7.4.1131

Answer (score 1):

Disabled and re-installed extension from http://adblockplus.org seems to work so far. This version only says 1.7.4 (not 1.7.4.1131) so might still get upgraded and break. Knowing how to rollback if that happens would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but, since it comes up as the second result when googling "adblock not saving filters", I feel it's still relevant to post here.

If you have NoScript installed, uninstall it and use something like uMatrix instead.  NoScript, despite being labeled as a security plugin, makes money from advertising and supports Google adsense, among others.  It specifically interferes with AdBlock Plus.

You can test this: Reset Firefox/Chrome and install AdBlock Plus, making sure to set at least one subscription.  Install any other addons you wish, restart after each install and check the AdBlock subscription status by hovering over the AdBlock icon. The sbuscriptions will remain.  Install NoScript.  Before restarting your browser, check AdBlock. The filter subscriptions will still be there.  Restart and suddenly they're gone. Remove NoScript, restart, and add your subscriptions again.  They should persist after restarting again.  If they don't you will need to reset your browser again.

Since NoScript has code that targets AdBlock specifically in order to disable features, you will need to reset anyway in order to get all of the subscription options to return.  At this point, Firefox will have a corrupted profile that requires the aforementioned reset.

https://adblockplus.org/blog/attention-noscript-users

Comment: Isn't this NoScript versus AdBlock Plus rumble a bit of ancient history?